# Multiple "And/Or" Condition Expressions spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to have a filter query using spring data JPA.
condition is something like this:

*(A or B or C) and D*

when I want to use Spring Data JPA I should change it to be like below (The precedence order is And then Or, just like Java.):

*(A and D) or (B and D) or (C and D)*

the code in the Spring Repository class is:

```
Page<SystemEntity>  findByNameContainsAndFlagIsFalseOrFamilyContainsAndFlagIsFalseOrEmailContainsAndFlagIsFalse(String name, String family ,String email, Pageable pageable);
```

you can see that the **D** condition at the above line "**AndFlagIsFalse**" is repeated 3 times.

is there any way to implement using a shorter format like "(A or B or C) and D"?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `@Query` annotation you can define the query directly:

```
@Query("SELECT se FROM SystemEntity se WHERE (se.name = :name AND se.flag = true) OR (. . .) OR (. . .)")
Page<SystemEntity> findSystemEntities(String name, String family ,String email, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: thank you bill Mair, I'm looking for a shorter format like "(A or B or C) and D" which is more easy and readable

Comment: Then your problem doesn't appear to be Java or JPA, you have a appear to have problems with boolean algebra.